# How to return a value back to main using accessor and object with array

Tags: c++

The below code works just fine except for the last bit (last 2 cout), the compiler doesn't return the value as it should, both the if statements doesn't compute and return appropriate value. Where did I do wrong, how can I rectify this? I use Codeblock.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

class Books
{
    private:
        string isbnNo, title, author;
        float price, discountedprice, discountperc;
    public:
        void set_Data();
        void calcDiscountedPrice();
        float getDiscountedPrice();
};
void Books :: set_Data()
{
    cout<<"\nEnter ISBN               : ";
    getline(cin, isbnNo);
    cout<<"Enter Title              : ";
    getline(cin, title);
    cout<<"Enter Author's name      : ";
    getline(cin, author);
    cout<<"Enter price              : ";
    cin>>price;
    cout<<"Enter discount (%)       : ";
    cin>>discountperc;
    cin.ignore();
}
void Books :: calcDiscountedPrice()
{
    discountperc/=100;
    discountedprice=price*discountperc;
    discountedprice=price-discountedprice;
}
float Books :: getDiscountedPrice()
{
        return discountedprice;
}
void func(Books x)
{
    x.set_Data();
    x.calcDiscountedPrice();
}
int main()
{
    Books B1;
    cout<<"Enter data for new incoming book this Month......"<<endl;
    func(B1);
    Books B2[5];
    cout<<"Now we shall enter and display data for 5 special books...."<<endl;
    float a=0;
    int b=0;
    for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
    {
        func(B2[i]);
        if(B2[i].getDiscountedPrice()>a)
        {
            a=B2[i].getDiscountedPrice();
        }
        if(B2[i].getDiscountedPrice()<30)
        {
            b++;
        }
    }
    cout<<"\n--------------------------------------------------------"<<endl;
    cout<<"The most expensive book is RM "<<a<<endl;
    cout<<"The number of books that are below RM 30 are : "<<b<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: You pass `Books` by value to `func()`, meaning that `x` is *a copy* of the parameter. And it just updates the copy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing `Books` by value to `func()`.

```
void func(Books x)
{
    x.set_Data();
    x.calcDiscountedPrice();
}
```

This strategy is known as pass by value. It just of copy not actual object.

You need to pass `Books` by reference into `func`. For more details please refer [How to pass objects to functions in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2139224/how-to-pass-objects-to-functions-in-c)